# Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 automatically checks in files

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I have a project in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 update 1. I'm using visual studio online(git version) as source repository.
recently visual studio automatically checks in all the added files and edited files. it doesn't show them in pending changes thus I can not commit them. And if I want to merge for example it says there are pending changes.
This started to happening after I installed update 1 for visual studio 2015 enterprise. 
Reinstalling VS or Git for windows already didn't work.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: What "Pending Changes"? Local changes appear in the "Changes" tab of the Team Explorer windows. Are you looking at the wrong window perhaps?

Comment: Yes, I meant changes tab. The added/edited files are not being shown so I can not commit. And they are not in excluded list. whenever I create a file, like a class or edit a file, Visual studio immediately marks them as Checked-In automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools > Options > Source Control > Environment and make sure that you have the options you expect checked.

The one that's probably relevant is the "Check in everything when closing a solution or project" option. Make sure that's unchecked.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, in my machine, in the Plug-in selection Microsoft Git Provider is selected so the Environment and visual studio team foundation server are not appearing.

Comment: @Milad I was more concerned with the options rather than the provider. Plus I realise that the options might not be exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you Chris, this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243682/disable-automatic-commit-of-changed-files-in-visual-studio-2013-to-git?rq=1 fixed the problem. I copied it from the machine where the repository was originally created and it worked. do you know about this file? Cause in other projects there's no sign of this file and they work just fine.

Comment: @Milad - not familiar with the git integration unfortunately